# Find and write the minimum number of instructions that you should give to end up with exactly N amoebas

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, puzzle

You have developed an artificial amoeba, and you can control exactly how it divides.
Each individual amoeba can be instructed to divide into **A, B, or C** amoebas. That
is, if you instruct an amoeba to divide into A, this amoeba will disappear, and  A different new amoeba will appear.

You start out with **K** amoeba initially, and you want to give them instructions
such that at the end, you have exactly **N** amoeba left. Giving an instruction is a
costly affair because it requires you to produce some biochemicals, and so you want to give as few instructions as possible.

**Find and write the minimum number of instructions that you should give to end up with exactly N amoebas**. If it cannot be done, write −1 instead. Note that each instruction is given to a single amoeba,
and not all of them together.

Find the minimum number of instructions needed for these instances:
**(a) K = 23, A = 7, B = 12, C = 16, N = 114

(b) K = 9, A = 7, B = 15, C = 16, N = 76**

> This problem is from pen & paper test, ZIO-2019.
>   My attempt:-
>   extra Amoebas to produce = 114 - 23 = 91
>   Amoeba added by each instruction, A = 6 , B =11 , C = 15
>   I manually tried to find , n(A)=1,n(B)=5,n(C)=2 .

**But my process took very long time, because im pretty noob in alogs.
So is there any mathematical method to get the answer , instead of trying to put each value manually to get the answer**

Answer (score 0):

This is the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), thinly disguised.  You have correctly analyzed your example.  Note that the question is equivalent to, "If we have a n unlimited number of coins of denominations $6$, $11$, and $15$, what is the minimum number of coins required to make change for a coin of denomination $91$?"  The only wrinkle is that if it requires more than $23$ coins, you have to report it just as if it can't be done at all.

The wiki article discusses solutions.

Comment: I don't understand the method, as i mentioned earlier this question is from a pen & paper test.  
so can you explain me here how to solve ?

Comment: What is that you don't understand?

Comment: What do mean by a pen and paper test?  It looks like a programming contest to me.

Comment: hey @saulspatz, the test he is mentioning is basically a written test for A&DS, now onto my query, I got to the point where I knew I had to basically see how $6, 11,15$ can form $91$ but I just couldn't figure out how that would work, so can you explain that?

Comment: @ShlokJainIt's explained in the wiki article.